# Setting a row of keys in a dictionary automaticaly

Tags: python

I have a python project to finish but I don't know how to divide the dictionary into x amount of equal pieces with using the basic modules that comes with python.

The output that I am looking is:

```
scrabble_dico = {2: , 3: ,..... , x:   }
```

Here is my code:

```
scrabble = {"A": 1, "B": 3, "C": 3, "D": 2, "E": 1, "F": 4, "G": 2, "H": 4, "I": 1,
            "J": 8, "K": 10, "L": 1, "M": 2, "N": 1, "O": 1, "P": 3, "Q": 8, "R": 1,
            "S": 1, "T": 1, "U": 1, "V": 4, "W": 10, "X": 10, "Y": 10, "Z": 10}

texte = "FSDKLHGIOQDSHGVIMOQSDVIOQDBSMIUQDBSMIUV"


def point(mot):
    points = 0
    for lettre in mot:
        points += scrabble[lettre]
    return points


print(point(texte))

fichier = open('scrabble.txt', "r")


def dico_scrabble(mot):
    scrabble_dico = {}
    ligne = [line.strip('\n') for line in fichier]
    for line in ligne:
            scrabble_dico[line] =point(line)
    return scrabble_dico


print(dico_scrabble(fichier))
```

The file `Fichier` is a list that contains a tremendous amount of values, so can't tell the exact number of value unfortunately.

Comment: It's unclear what you're looking for. Give concrete examples of inputs and outputs, and also the outputs you're currently getting. The example output you gave is not in at all valid Python.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Your question is about splitting a dict, but your posted code seems to focus on input mechanics and game evaluation.  Please reduce your question to a single issue.

Comment: ok, my issue is with the second function, the output that I am looking for is that a word comes from a list that the file Fichier contains, uses the first function to take a point then add it fo the dictionary scrabble_dico for example: AA = 2 points and the output that I am looking is scrabble_dico ={2:{AA:2, BB:3,} 3:{}} and so on each little dictionary (2 :{} ,3: {},4 {}, 5:{}) has to contain 15 word , I hope that it was a better explanation

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general suggestion about splitting a dictionary in two pieces:

```
d = {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3, 'key4': 4, 'key5': 5}
d1 = dict(list(d.items())[len(d)//2:])
d2 = dict(list(d.items())[:len(d)//2])
```

If you print d1:

```
{'key1': 1, 'key5': 5, 'key4': 4}
```

If you print d2:

```
{'key3': 3, 'key2': 2}
```

You can use the same logic to split it even in smaller chunks.

The main tool used here is called **slicing**:

> The slice() function returns a slice object.
>
> A slice object is used to specify how to slice a sequence. You can
> specify where to start the slicing, and where to end. You can also
> specify the step, which allows you to e.g. slice only every other
> item.

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/slice.html) you can read its official documentation and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_slice.asp) you find a lesson with exercises.

Comment: Hello, did you have a moment to check my reply? If it was useful for you please consider upvoting it and / or choosing it as final answer. Thanks for your time!